# I have a trigger on one of my tables and I want to use it on another table but it won't work

Tags: mysql, database, triggers, concatenation

I have a before insert trigger on one table. What it does is the following:
place a string and some zeros before the id and add it to `deelnemers` table. Now I have a second table (in the same database) and I copy pasted the same trigger there but it won't work. All I get are zeros as entries in de 'deelnemernr' column. For the first table it works perfectly by the way. Here is my trigger code:

```
BEGIN
INSERT INTO deelnemers_seq VALUES (NULL);
SET NEW.deelnemernr = CONCAT('lol16', LPAD(LAST_INSERT_ID(), 3, '0'));
END
```

Comment: It might have something to do with the settings of the columns. In the first table I had to tweak some settings that I forgot.

Comment: I have found the solution already! Question.closed = true;